# Use scale() function to standard deviation without centering

Tags: r

In the data set that I'm analyzing, I have a selection of variables that I would like to scale to 1 standard deviation, but not center. I tried this using the `scale()`function in the example below.

```
require(tidyverse)

set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(replicate(10, sample(0:1000, 1000, rep = TRUE)))
scaled_vars <- df %>%
    select(X1 : X6) %>%
    map(~scale(., center = F)
```

However, from reading the `scale()`documentation, if `center = F` then the scaling is performed to the root mean square, not the standard deviation. The documentation states that to scale to standard deviation without centering, to use the code:

```
scale(x, center = FALSE, scale = apply(x, 2, sd, na.rm = T))
```

However, I cannot seem to get that code to work within my `map` function.

```
map(~scale(., center = F, scale = apply(., 2, sd, na.rm = T)
```

The error message states that object 'x' cannot be found. How can I adjust my code to achieve my aim? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` loops through each of the column.  The `scale` argument in `scale` function takes the `sd` for that particular column.  The `apply` based approach is when we have multiple columns.

```
out <- df %>% 
         select(X1:X6) %>% 
         map_df(~ scale(.x, center = FALSE, scale = sd(.x, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

-checking with the output generated from OP's base R code

```
out1 <- scale(df[1:6], center = FALSE, 
         scale = apply(df[1:6], 2, sd, na.rm = TRUE))

all.equal(as.matrix(out), out1, check.attributes = FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the solution so quickly. I notice that your solution provides the same answers as setting ```scale = T``` and ```center = T``` Is there something about my code which has means my data is automatically centered?

Comment: @Paul I am getting similar output with the `base R` version you showed

Comment: I can see that your solution has produced the same output as ```base R```. I think there must be something on the statistics side of thing I haven't grasped. I will need to go and do some more reading. Thanks again.

Comment: @Paul If you check the description in the `?scale` `The value of ‘center’ determines how column centering is
     performed.  If ‘center’ is a numeric vector with length equal to
     the number of columns of ‘x’, then each column of ‘x’ has the
     corresponding value from ‘center’ subtracted from it.  If ‘center’
     is ‘TRUE’ then centering is done by subtracting the column means
     (omitting ‘NA’s) of ‘x’ from their corresponding columns, and if
     ‘center’ is ‘FALSE’, no centering is done.`

Comment: @Paul So, by giving only TRUE, or FALSE, it is doing the centering for each of the column `m1 <- matrix(1:30, 5, 6);
 d1 <- as.data.frame(m1);
scale(d1, center = FALSE, scale = TRUE)` and check `scale(d1, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)`

Comment: I made a mistake. When used in my regression models, the outputs are the same whether using ```map_df(~ scale(.x, center = FALSE, scale = sd(.x, na.rm = TRUE)))``` or ```scale = T, center = T```, except for the intercept, which is the only output that should be different.